How to move a class function (which uses constructor db) to separated file?
In my nestJS application I'm using services like this:
src/app/photo/photo.service.ts
import { Db, GridFSBucket } from 'mongodb'

@Injectable()
export class PhotoService { // <-
    constructor(
        @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION')
        private db: Db
    ) {}

    async stream(buckenName, contentType, id, res) {
        const Bucket = new GridFSBucket(this.db, { bucketName })

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

        Bucket.openDownloadStream(id)
        .on('data', (chunk) => res.write(chunk))
        .on('end', () => res.end())
        .on('error', (err) => { throw err })
    }

    async anotherFunction() {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

In another file there is also the same stream function:
src/app/video/video.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class VideoService { // <-
    constructor(
        @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION')
        private db: Db
    ) {}

    async stream(buckenName, contentType, id, res) {
        const Bucket = new GridFSBucket(this.db, { bucketName })

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

        Bucket.openDownloadStream(id)
        .on('data', (chunk) => res.write(chunk))
        .on('end', () => res.end())
        .on('error', (err) => { throw err })
    }

    async anotherFunction() {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

So it is obvious, that this function should be reused. But I'm not quite shure how to refactor this.
src/lib/helper.ts
export async stream(buckenName, contentType, id, res) {
    const Bucket = new GridFSBucket(this.db, { bucketName })

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

    Bucket.openDownloadStream(id)
    .on('data', (chunk) => res.write(chunk))
    .on('end', () => res.end())
    .on('error', (err) => { throw err })
}

But how do I import this file in the services?
import { stream } from '../../lib/helper'

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
    constructor(
        @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION')
        private db: Db
    ) {}

    // how to import stream() here ???

    async anotherFunction() {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

The problem for me is db, which is set in the constructor...

You mean VideoService.prototype.stream = stream;?

You could simply pass db as an additional parameter to your stream(...) function, and call it from a class method of the same name.
// helper.ts
export async function streamHelper(db, bucketName, contentType, id, res) {
    const Bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName })

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

    Bucket.openDownloadStream(id)
    .on('data', (chunk) => res.write(chunk))
    .on('end', () => res.end())
    .on('error', (err) => { throw err })
}

import { streamHelper } from '../../lib/helper'

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
    constructor(
        @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION')
        private db: Db
    ) {}

    // (not async because streamHelper already returns a promise)
    stream(bucketName, contentType, id, res) {
        return streamHelper(this.db, bucketName, contentType, id, res)
    }

    async anotherFunction() {
        // do some stuff
    }
}


You could also use inheritance and declare stream on the parent class, then have PhotoService and VideoService inherit the method
class ParentService {
    constructor(private db) {}

    async stream(bucketName, contentType, id, res) {
        const Bucket = new GridFSBucket(this.db, { bucketName })

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

        Bucket.openDownloadStream(id)
        .on('data', (chunk) => res.write(chunk))
        .on('end', () => res.end())
        .on('error', (err) => { throw err })
    }
}

class VideoService extends ParentService {
  constructor(..., db) {
    ...
    super(db)
  }
}

Then you can call new VideoService().stream(...) just like before

Where is @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION') needed in your second solution? Both constructors?

I'm not entirely familiar with  Angular's injection system, but I believe the injection annotations should be either the parent class or in both child classes, but not both parent and child
